# Issue with "where" in an associated query in Symfony 3

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I'm trying to make a "search engine" for my app; the table I want to show, contains two fields which are associated to another tables.

I'm using this query:

```
Select work from WorkBundle:Work work
       where work.client.name like '$search%'
```

Work, is associated with the tables "user" and "client", I have the associations correctly defined so I don't have to use the inner join statement, but I get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 68 near 'nombre like 'fsdf%'': Error: Class WorkBundle\Entity\Work has no field or association named client.nombre
```

I don't know how to access to the "name" field which is on the "client" table.

Actually I can do the same by using a full inner join query and it works but I can't use it in my app.

Comment: Are you using SQL or DQL? Can you provide a part of your controller or repository class with this query in?

Comment: *Actually i can do the same by using a full inner join query and it works but i cant use it in my app.*.... why?

Comment: im using DQL, but i dont know wich part of the controller or repositore provide :S

Comment: There is any way to search in the objet array, if i have this query: Select w from WorkBundle:Work w, can i search some patern in the objet array?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure but it seems you cant use selectors like `work.client.name`. I think it based on doctrine uses "lazy" queries. So you must use table joins in this case.
So it should look smth like that

```
// work repository
public function findByKeyword($keyword)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("w");
    $result = $qb
        ->add('where', $qb->expr()->like("wc.name", ':keyword'))
        ->leftjoin("w.client", "wc") //or join or innerjoin depends of your case
        ->setParameters([
            'keyword' => $keyword
        ])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didnt solve the problem, maybe i need to find some way to search in the array dat the query gives